# Unwanted transforms in animation

Tags: animation

I used animations from [Mixamo](https://www.mixamo.com/) for a game project, a humanoid character (ybot). I used an add-on called [Godot Game Tools](https://viniguerrero.itch.io/godot-game-tools) to combine different animations and duplicate them. I duplicated the animations and modified the rotations of spine bone and replaced the key frames. When I opened the project later the animation had some unwanted transforms in it. The character is shifted slightly to up.

Screenshots:
[image: screenshot]

When I was modifying this animation there was no such problems, when I changed the animation to something else and back the problem occurred. Every animation I made this way has problems like this. I did it yesterday and I noticed this today when I opened my Blender project.

As a workaround for now I opened each animation and changed the transform of the hip bone individually. I have to again modify many animations to correct this.

Is this a bug ? What causes this problem and why ? How can I fix it ?

Please help!

Edit: Here's the blend file

[image]

Comment: Please share blend with before and after armature via https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com

Comment: I think the problem is when I key frame, the root bone (Hip) changes its position. I'll try to provide a blend file.

Comment: When I created a new project and did this, this glitch is not seen, It maybe my fault :D. Should I delete the question ?. Sorry for the trouble.

Comment: if you provide more info to your question, so you or others will be able to answer it, you can keep it. (Also others can get into the same issue.)  But ... like now, it would be better to delete it. Thank you

Comment: I thought I solved this problem and again it reappeared, I have provided the blend file. The original file had many files and it was 100 MB, I deleted most of the animations to reduce the file size. Please help

Comment: Once this glitch comes it spreads to the other modified animations like a disease in the original blend file. Every animation I have modified is above the ground, there are more than 20 animations affected.

Comment: Any idea anybody ?

Comment: Since nobody ... I cant reproduce it. Can you share screencast of your worklow? If I go to NLA > Push Down Action (imported one) > Keyframe changes > Bake Action.

Comment: I don't understand what you meant by workflow. I modified the animation in the Action Editor. I don't actually know much about animations and whether it is the right way to modify the animations. If I switch the current animation like crazy the root bone (hip) will change its position. Is it because the animations gets corrupted ?

Comment: I'm not sure how you was able to do transforms in Action editor, but I'm not so experienced as well so probably someone  can answer better. I will try to answer what I would do in your case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use **Replace** blending mode for these strips, but I would say you probably used **Add** when you edited action. Changing back to "Add" blend type - seems solved the issue here.

[image]

There of course matter what blend mode you used while editing, also there matters what action is used bellow.

[image]

---

**BTW**

To do changes on imported animations I would use NLA editor to adjust animation. If you use GGT add-on its automatically imported as NLA action strips (animations).

I cleaned up all unused tracks and left only one to keep it more clear.
("Riffle_Crouch_Walk")

[image]
[image]

**Action editor**
- create a new action
(or delete existing and add keyframe for selected bones in Pose mode)
- here you can do all edits that are Replaced, Added or what ever (is set in NLA strip properties) on top of imported track (action)

**NLA editor**
- top action is always used (if not disabled)
- top row (with dope sheet icon) is always editable one
- all bellow (with star icon) are "Push Down" for strip mixing
(like now "Riffle_Crouch_Walk" imported action)

When you finish edits, you can search "Bake Action" (with cursor inside NLA editor) into one animation.

See blend file
[image]

Comment: Thank you for helping, but any idea why the root bone (hip) got displaced in the animations aim down and up animations ?.

Comment: @Icosagon: OK, it seems to me I got it, check beginning of the answer.

Comment: Thanks for helping